# how to change a div from an iframe in another div

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have two divs

```
        <div id="leftdiv"><!--#exec cgi="test.cgi"--></div> 
        <div id="rigthdiv" >
            <iframe name="rigthdiv" class="contentiframe"allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" src="iframebg.html"><body STYLE="background- color:transparent"></iframe>
        </div>
```

I am trying to change the leftdiv from iframe. I called the js below from the iframe but nothing changed. What's wrong? Thanks

```
         function test() {
             parent.document.getElementById("leftdiv").innerHTML = 'Processing complete.';  
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work on chrome, but it can work on firefox or IE. Chrome doesn't support iframe normally when you use javascript. You can try to use JQuery.